# R: how to change lattice (levelplot) color theme?

Tags: r, graphics, colors, lattice

The default theme on my installation is something which maps the values to pink and cyan. How to change it for example to a gray scale theme?

Answer (score 16):

You can use

```
library(lattice)
lattice.options(default.theme = standard.theme(color = FALSE))
```

which turns on black-and-white suitable for printing.  I've also played with things like

```
sb <- trellis.par.get("strip.background") 
sb[["col"]][1] <- "lightgray"
trellis.par.set("strip.background", sb)
```

which changes just the header background.

And I thought people only asked [ggplot2](http://cran.r-project.org/package=ggplot2) questions here :)  Nice to see some [lattice](http://cran.r-project.org/package=lattice) for a change.

Comment: indeed, with enough effort one may convince lattice to produce plots that have [little to envy to ggplot2's polished looks](http://latticeextra.r-forge.r-project.org/#layer&theme=ggplot2like). There's no latticelike theme for ggplot2 that I know of.

Comment: This did not work, at least not within org-mode. Had to use `trellis.par.set(canonical.theme(color = FALSE))`

Comment: @Henrik Same for me - thanks for sharing your solution!

Answer (score 13):

Thanks for the answers guys! It also helped me to find more information on the subject. I learned that I can control the scales of gray using for example the following:

```
levelplot(my_var, col.regions = gray(0:100/100))
```

which gives me 100 shades of gray from black (0) to white (1).

I'm using the function to plot gray scale images (photos) which I've pre-processed to a double matrix. I don't know if it's the best possible approach, but so far it works and I believe it gives me more options for graphing than the basic displaying options in the EBImage and rimage libraries. I don't know how I'd alter the palette to match displaying color images, but I'm glad I didn't have to do that so far...

Comment: If you have 256 levels of gray in your image (8bit), maybe gray(0:255/255) would be closer to the original?

Comment: Hey, a good tip! Although in the case of my images I stop seeing differences with values up from 50.

Answer (score 5):

There are many ways to accomplish your request. The simplest is:

```
trellis.device(color = FALSE)
```

another is

```
ltheme <- canonical.theme(color = FALSE) ## in-built B&W theme 
ltheme$strip.background$col <- "transparent" ## change strip bg 
lattice.options(default.theme = ltheme) ## set as default
```

See this mail archive item: [Re: [R] specify lattice black-and-white theme](http://www.mail-archive.com/r-help@r-project.org/msg64699.html) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

You may also want to consider using `panel.levelplot.raster`, as it reduces the figure size sizably, as I recently found out. Combining this tip with changing trellis settings in general, here are a following examples:

```
trellis.par.set(regions=list(col=topo.colors(100)))
levelplot(volcano, panel = panel.levelplot.raster)

levelplot(volcano, panel = panel.levelplot.raster,
          par.settings=list(regions=list(col=topo.colors(100))))
```

The second method is deceptive because the trellis settings are in fact being changed globally. I didn't know about the col.regions argument though - that's pretty nice as it  seems to change the color theme locally.

Answer (score 2):

The only one that worked for me is:

```
>trellis.par.set(canonical.theme(color = FALSE))
```