# Showing data values on levelplot in R

Tags: r, graphics, lattice

I wonder if it is possible to show data values on levelplot (lattice package) in *R*. I'd appreciate if someone help me to do that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean to have a value for each cell?

Comment: Yes. I'd like to show data also on the plot.

Comment: @MYaseen208: Please post a reproducible example, as detailed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Don't bother. Show a table instead.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can write your own panel function, e.g.:

```
library("lattice")
x <- seq(pi/4, 5*pi, length.out=10)
y <- seq(pi/4, 5*pi, length.out=10)
r <- as.vector(sqrt(outer(x^2, y^2, "+")))
grid <- expand.grid(x=x, y=y)
grid$z <- cos(r^2)*exp(-r/(pi^3))

p <- levelplot(z~x*y, grid, 
               panel=function(...) {
                       arg <- list(...)
                       panel.levelplot(...)
                       panel.text(arg$x, arg$y, round(arg$z,1))})
print(p)
```

[image: panel.levelplot example]

Comment: Check also similar plot on [lmdvr site](http://lmdvr.r-forge.r-project.org/figures/figures.html?chapter=13;figure=13_05;theme=stdColor;code=right).

Comment: In the above example, how can we change the default theme?

Comment: E.g. `levelplot(z~x*y, grid, col.regions = heat.colors(100))`. Also check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712402/r-how-to-change-lattice-levelplot-color-theme