# How to show matrix values on Levelplot

Tags: r, visualization, data-visualization, lattice

I have a matrix data [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cqxj4wx2czi9j4e/J_H2S1T6_PassTraffic.csv), and I visualized it with  `levelplot`. The Plot is placed below. But I just couldn't put the values into the plot, I mean I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569666/showing-data-values-on-levelplot-in-r), but still couldn't figure it out.

How can I do that ? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

The problem with the code in the answer you linked to is that it only works when the objects in the levelplot's formula are named `x`, `y`, and `z`.

Here is an example that uses a more standard idiom for processing the arguments passed in to the custom panel function and so becomes more generally applicable:

```
library("lattice")

## Example data
x <- seq(pi/4, 5*pi, length.out=10)
y <- seq(pi/4, 5*pi, length.out=10)
grid <- expand.grid(X=x, Y=y)
grid$Z <- runif(100, -1, 1)

## Write a panel function (after examining 'args(panel.levelplot) to see what
## will be being passed on to the panel function by levelplot())
myPanel <- function(x, y, z, ...) {
    panel.levelplot(x,y,z,...)
    panel.text(x, y, round(z,1))
}

## Try it out
levelplot(Z ~ X*Y, grid, panel = myPanel)
```

[image]

Comment: Old answer I know but how might I go about excluding NA values from displaying a text label with this example panel function?

Comment: @RichWawrzonek Inside of `myPanel`, I'd explicitly convert `z` to a character vector and then change all of the `NA`s to empty strings. Something like this for the body of `myPanel`: `{panel.levelplot(x,y,z,...); zz <- as.character(round(z,1)); zz[is.na(zz)] <- ""; panel.text(x, y, zz)}`

Answer (score 4):

```
mat <- read.csv("J_H2S1T6_PassTraffic.csv", header=F)

y        <- as.numeric(mat[1,-1])
mat      <- mat[-1,-1]
n        <- dim(mat)[1]
```

Here a modification, I generate a new scale

```
x <- seq(min(y), max(y), length.out=n)
grid     <- expand.grid(x=x, y=x)
mat      <- as.matrix(mat)
dim(mat) <- c(n*n,1)
grid$z   <- mat
```

Here the modification. I change the dimension of the matrix to a vector to put it in the grid .

```
mat <- as.matrix(mat)
dim(mat) <- c(n*n,1)
grid$z <- mat

p <- levelplot(z~x*y, grid, 
           panel=function(...) {
             arg <- list(...)
             panel.levelplot(...)
             panel.text(arg$x, arg$y,arg$z)},
           scales = list(y = list(at=y,labels=y),
                         x = list(at=y,labels=y)))

print(p)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use `layer()` from **latticeExtra**. It allows you to overlay one plot on top of another, using the `+` operator familiar to **ggplot2** enthusiasts:

```
library(latticeExtra)

## Applied to the example data in my other answer, this will produce
## an identical plot
levelplot(Z ~ X*Y, data = grid) +
layer(panel.text(X, Y, round(Z, 1)), data = grid)
```