# 2 color heatmap in R with middle color anchored to a specific value

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2, gradient

This heatmap image was generated in Excel but as I'm trying to learn R I would like to know how to make a heatmap like that with R.

[image: Excel HeatMap]

Right now, this code is working but not as it was supposed to...

```
(p <- ggplot(melt(heat), aes(Var2, Var1))
 + geom_tile(aes(fill = value), colour = "white")
 + scale_fill_gradient(low = "red", high = "green"))
```

I would like to have 2 gradients, green(highest value) to white (the number 1000) to red(lowest value). Is it possible in R?

heat dataset:

```
> heat[0:10,0:10]
          [,1]     [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]      [,7]      [,8]      [,9]     [,10]
 [1,] 1000.000    0.000    0.0000    0.0000  757.0317  709.3896  843.7676  932.2801    0.0000 1016.7203
 [2,] 1087.658 1000.000    0.0000    0.0000  935.5829  854.5110  889.5042 1091.4610  929.1611    0.0000
 [3,] 1181.599 1361.953 1000.0000    0.0000    0.0000 1102.1590 1147.1300  984.1374  969.0718 1058.3456
 [4,] 1319.012 1405.954 1187.5215 1000.0000    0.0000 1093.8854 1195.7298 1077.0797 1119.4640 1159.5207
 [5,]    0.000    0.000  909.1927  817.5097 1000.0000    0.0000 1101.2891 1064.6516 1037.1623  990.3974
 [6,]    0.000    0.000    0.0000    0.0000  887.7498 1000.0000 1015.9835 1062.1668 1105.2163  983.2319
 [7,]    0.000    0.000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000 1000.0000  911.0699 1026.1989  951.3572
 [8,]    0.000    0.000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000 1000.0000  834.8725  927.6802
 [9,] 1261.824    0.000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000 1000.0000  795.6285
[10,]    0.000 1121.210    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000 1000.0000
```

Comment: it should be possible if you give a reprooducible example? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use  ?`scale_fill_gradientn`

gving you values:

```
  library(scales)
  heat.dat <- heat[0:10,0:10]
  dat <- expand.grid(var1=1:10, var2=1:10)
  dat$value <- melt(heat.dat)$value
  ggplot(dat, aes(x=var1,y=var2))+ 
        geom_tile(aes(fill = value),colour='white')+
        scale_fill_gradientn(colours=c("red","white","green"),
         values  = rescale(c(min(dat$value), 1000, max(dat$value)))
```

[image]

Using Lattice:

```
with(dat,
levelplot(round(value,0)~y*x, 
          dat, 
          panel=function(...) {
                 arg <- list(...)
                 panel.levelplot(...)
                 panel.text(arg$x, arg$y,arg$z)},
          scales = list(y = list(at=y,labels=y),
                        x = list(at=y,labels=y)),
          col.regions = colorRampPalette(c("red", "white", "green"),interpolate ='spline'))
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tweaked it a little after some more google research:

`(p <- ggplot(melt(heat[0:10,0:10]), aes(Var2, Var1))
 + geom_tile(aes(fill = value), colour = "white")
 + scale_fill_gradientn(colours=c("red", "white", "green"),
     values=rescale(c(min(heat[0:10,0:10]), 1000, max(heat[0:10,0:10]))),
                     guide="colorbar"))`

This way the number 1000 will be always white and the other colors will be positioned accordingly.

Comment: does this answer you question? but I think if what you want is to show numbers as excel it is better, in this case to use levelplot of lattice package, here an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13895480/how-to-show-matrix-values-on-levelplot/13895940#13895940

Comment: How do you make this that the cells in the original data would match the cells that are plotted with ggplot. The values are inverted.

Comment: @agstudy I like this solution but how do you manage if you have 5 colors? I tried adding intermediate values to 'rescale' but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer and comments of / to `agstudy`, you can also use pure ggplot syntax and map the labels within the aes() via `label`:

```
    heat=structure(c(1000, 1087.658, 1181.599, 1319.012, 0, 0, 0, 0, 261.824,0, 0, 1000, 1361.953, 1405.954, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1121.21, 0, 0,1000, 187.5215, 909.1927, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1000, 817.5097,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 57.0317, 935.5829, 0, 0, 1000, 887.7498, 0, 0,0, 0, 709.3896, 854.511, 1102.159, 093.8854, 0, 1000, 0, 0,0, 0, 843.7676, 889.5042, 1147.13, 1195.7298, 1101.2891, 015.9835,1000, 0, 0, 0, 932.2801, 1091.461, 984.1374, 1077.0797, 1064.6516,1062.1668, 911.0699, 1000, 0, 0, 0, 929.1611, 969.0718, 1119.464,1037.1623, 1105.2163, 1026.1989, 834.8725, 1000, 0, 1016.7203,0, 058.3456, 1159.5207, 990.3974, 983.2319, 951.3572, 927.6802,795.6285, 1000), Dim  c(10L, 10L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, NULL))

    heat_melted = reshape2::melt(heat[10:0,0:10])

    ggplot(heat_melted, aes(Var2, Var1, label = round(value))) +   
    geom_tile(aes(fill = value),  colour = "white") +   
    scale_fill_gradientn(colours=c("red", "white", "green"), 
    values=rescale(c(min(heat_melted$value), 1000, max(heat_melted$value))), guide="colorbar") +
    geom_text()
```

[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWGQ6.png)