# How to customise the colour for middle and maximum value in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14000232/2-color-heatmap-in-r-with-middle-color-anchored-to-a-specific-value) link, trying to

- make 0 as white
- values more than 2 the same colour

The code below

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
ran <- matrix(nrow = 3, ncol = 2, c(-2,-1,0,1,2,3))
ran_melt <- melt(ran)
ggplot(ran_melt, aes(Var1, Var2)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value), color = "white") +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c("red", "white", "blue"),
                       values = rescale(c(min(ran_melt$value), 0, max(ran_melt$value)))) +
  labs(fill = 'legend')
```

will plot this

[image]

If I change `max(ran_melt$value)` to `2`:

```
ggplot(ran_melt, aes(Var1, Var2)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value), color = "white") +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c("red", "white", "blue"),
                       values = rescale(c(min(ran_melt$value), 0, 2))) +
  labs(fill = 'legend')
```

I got this:
[image]

So how can I achieve my two goals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use arguments `limits` and `oob` in `scale_fill_gradientn` to achieve what you're after:

```
ggplot(ran_melt, aes(Var1, Var2)) +
    geom_tile(aes(fill = value), color = "white") +
    scale_fill_gradientn(
        colours = c("red", "white", "blue"),
        limits = c(-2, 2),
        oob = squish) +
  labs(fill = 'legend')
```

[image]

Explanation: `oob = squish` gives values that lie *outside* of `limits` the same colour/fill value as the min/max of `limits`. See e.g. `?scale_fill_gradientn` for details on `oob`.

---

### Update

If you have asymmetric `limits` you can use argument `values` with `rescale`:

```
ggplot(ran_melt, aes(Var1, Var2)) +
    geom_tile(aes(fill = value), color = "white") +
    scale_fill_gradientn(
        colours = c("red", "white", "blue"),
        limits = c(-1, 2),
        values = rescale(c(-1, 0, 2)),
        oob = squish) +
    labs(fill = 'legend')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but in this case, the 0 value should be in the middle of the `limits` so that it can be white. Can I make 0 value still white while setting `limits = c(-1, 2)`?

Comment: @lanselibai I don't understand your comment. The `0` value *is* in the middle and white in above example! If you have non-symmetric limits this will not work.

Comment: Okay, is there a way that from -1 to 0: red to white; from 0 to 2: white to blue?

Comment: @lanselibai Sure, please take a look at my updated answer.