# Make color palette of discretized values for a continuous variable (lattice levelplot)

Tags: r, graphics, colors, lattice, discretization

Following up on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46842118/r-levelplot-color-green-white-red-white-on-0-according-to-one-variable-but-s), I want to make a levelplot heat map and color each cell according to the variable `p.value` in my data frame.

I would like to have the cells colored in such way that there are only 3 colors (discretized color palette for continuous variable):

- **white** for p.values >0.05
- **red** for p.values <0.05 and >0.01
- **dark red** for p.values <0.01

So far this is my MWE.

```
set.seed(150)
pv.df <- data.frame(compound=rep(LETTERS[1:8], each=3), comparison=rep(c("a/b","b/c","a/c"), 8), p.value=runif(24, 0, 0.2))
pv.df
myPanel <- function(x, y, z, ...) {
  panel.levelplot(x, y, z, ...)
  panel.text(x, y, round(z, 2))
}
#install.packages("latticeExtra")
library(latticeExtra)
library(RColorBrewer)
cols <- rev(colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(6, "Reds"))(10))

png(filename="test.png", height=1000, width=600)
print(
    levelplot(p.value ~ comparison*compound,
          pv.df,
          panel = myPanel,
          col.regions = cols,
          colorkey = list(col = cols, 
                          at = do.breaks(range(pv.df$p.value), 10)),
          xlab = "", ylab = "",              # remove axis titles
          scales = list(x = list(rot = 45),  # change rotation for x-axis text
                        cex = 0.8),          # change font size for x- & y-axis text
          main = list(label = "Total FAME abundance - TREATMENT",
                      cex = 1.5))            # change font size for plot title
)
dev.off()
```

Which produces:

[image: test]

I am showing the actual `p.value` values in the levelplot. There seems to be a problem with the code above, since that "0.14" is colored darker than the "0.08" right next to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specifiy the breakpoints to use for the regions (as you did for the colorkey), hence the mishmash in the color.

If you want the regions to be `<=0.01`, `>0.01 & <=0.05` and `>0.05` you need to specify it inside the `levelplot` call with the `at` parameter (and of course the same for the `colorkey`).

So, in the call, you need to tell that you want the colors "darkred", "red", and "white" for the different region (`col.regions = c("darkred", "red", "white")`) with breaks at 0 (actually lower bound), 0.01, 0.05, and 0.20 (upperbound, which is a kind of rounding for the maximum `p.value` of your `data.frame`).

Your `levelplot` call is then:

```
levelplot(p.value ~ comparison*compound,
          pv.df,
          panel = myPanel,
          col.regions = c("darkred", "red", "white"),
          at=c(0, 0.01, 0.05, 0.20),
          colorkey = list(col = c("darkred", "red", "white"), 
                          at = c(0, 0.01, 0.05, 0.20)),
          xlab = "", ylab = "",              # remove axis titles
          scales = list(x = list(rot = 45),  # change rotation for x-axis text
                        cex = 0.8),          # change font size for x- & y-axis text
          main = list(label = "Total FAME abundance - TREATMENT",
                      cex = 1.5))
```

Giving:

[image]

***N.B.:*** *I based the call on your description of breaks, for the breaks you used in your code, you need to add `at = do.breaks(range(pv.df$p.value), 10))` in the call (for example, after defining the `col.regions`)*